# Create nested dropdown style in Laravel array

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

i am **trying to display data** from array in a Dropdown in Laravel 5.2. Here is how my array looks like:

[image]

And here is another presentation on `return` array data from my controller.

[image]

Here is how my view looks like, its simple dropdown which i am trying to create:

```
<select class="form-control" name="service_id">
    <option value="">Select...</option>
    @foreach($serviceslist as $serviceli)
        <option value="{{$serviceli->id}}">
            {{$serviceli->servicename}}
        </option>                               
    @endforeach
</select>
```

And my **controller** function in laravel is like this:

```
public function create()
{
    $services = $this->getCategories();

    return View::make('services.create')->with('serviceslist', $services);
}

private function getCategories($parentId = 0)
{
    $categories = [];

    foreach(Services::where('service_id', $parentId)->get() as $category)
    {
        $categories[] = [
            'item'     => $category,
            'children' => $this->getCategories($category->id)
        ];
     }
     return $categories;
 }
```

Here i have created a function `getCategory()` in the same controller to create the array.

When i run the code i get this error.

```
Trying to get property of non-object (View: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/laravelCRM/resources/views/services/create.blade.php)
```

I try to do `getCollection()` as well on my view (blade template), but it also didnt work. Where is the issue?

Thank you! (in advance)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing an array to the view instead of an instance of Collection, therefore you can't run `getCollection()` on an array.

Replace `return $categories;` with `return collect($categories);`

You can also do `return Collection::make($categories);`